# ASP.Net core with attribute routing on IIS Express gives 503 error when published

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, attributerouting

I have a ASP.NET core MVC controller with attribute routing that works well locally ,like https://localhost:44322/adfs/account/login  , however 503(Service Unavailable) error is returned when published on the IIS, also other routes without attribute routing works fine.No error logs in event viewer for the same.

```
   [SecurityHeaders] 
   [Route("adfs/account")]
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
    {//some code}
   }
```

In Startup.cs

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment 
          env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
                                     "default-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:");
            await next();
        });
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: In IIS, is your application hosted under the main site as adfs? If it is, it could be the issue you are getting 503. It would be good to see the screenshot of how the application is setup in IIS

Comment: Its called SKMIdenity uses Application Identity in Application Pool

Comment: so where is your `AccountController` under `SKMIdentity` or `adfs`?

Comment: SKMIdentity  is my site name , Account controller has route like /adfs/account

Comment: sounds strange that you are getting 503 for a particular route and all other routes work correctly. If the service is unavailable, all other routes shouldn't work. Also, I can see that you have an adfs application in IIS. Try stopping that, although I don't think it should interfere, but see if that makes a difference.